# sed - Return characters before pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed, cygwin

```
 $  echo "ABC XYZ 12/123/52/ ABBDBDAD 562.4224.32 02381831522" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g' raw.tmp
```

Using the above, I am trying to extract ABC XYZ from a line (spaces preserved). My regex returns ABCXYZABBDBDAD: I am a noob at regex and still have a lot to learn.

In summary, how do I get the substring ABC XYZ from a line before a number with whitespace preceding it?

Answer (score 3):

This can make it:

```
$ echo "ABC XYZ 12/123/52/ ABBDBDAD 562.4224.32 02381831522" | sed -n 's/\([A-Z]* [A-Z]*\) [0-9]*.*/\1/p' 
ABC XYZ
```

#### Explanation:

```
sed -n 's/\([A-Z]* [A-Z]*\) [0-9]*.*/\1/p' 

  \([A-Z]* [A-Z]*\)  == catch WORD + space + WORD
       [0-9]*.*      == some number + space + rest of string
  /\1/p              == print catched string
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this one

```
echo "ABC XYZ 12/123/52/ ABBDBDAD 562.4224.32 02381831522" | sed -n 's/^\([a-zA-Z ]\+\).*/\1/gp' > raw.tmp
```

Or more accurately

```
echo "ABC XYZ 12/123/52/ ABBDBDAD 562.4224.32 02381831522" | sed -n 's/^\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]\+[a-zA-Z]\).*/\1/gp'
```

Which restricts characters that begin with letters and ends up with letters as well.

Answer (score 0):

You  need to write following

```
echo "ABC XYZ 12/123/52/ ABBDBDAD 562.4224.32 02381831522" | sed 's/.*\(ABC XYZ\).*/\1/g'
```

Output

`ABC XYZ`

Point is - I believe you are trying to extract 'ABC XYZ' (exactly). So you extract that and substitute entire line with it

**Edit** I think i missed the point. You basically want 'Str1 Str2 '

In that case following works

```
echo "ABC XYZ 12/123/52/ ABBDBDAD 562.4224.32 02381831522" | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z ][a-zA-Z ]*\).*/\1/g'
```